# Java Calculator: Arithmetic operators do not appear on the screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, calculator

I made a calculator in Java but I want to show the arithmetic operators in the screen. I dont know why this dont happen, I think it is because the method calcular overwrite immediatly, I dont know. To make the reset in screen I used a boolean variable called reset.

I made comments to clarify the code. Maybe the error is in the class Operadores or in the method Calcular.

PD: Im relatively new in Java, so any suggestion to my code is well received.

Greetings :)

```
package reto1;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
public class Reto1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        MarcoCalculadora micalculadora = new MarcoCalculadora();
        micalculadora.setVisible(true);
        micalculadora.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

               
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
class MarcoCalculadora extends JFrame{
    
    //Establecemos el acomodo del marco de la calculadora
    BorderLayout acomodoMarco = new BorderLayout();
    
    //Hacemos el constructor para dar caracteristicas al marco
    public MarcoCalculadora(){
        setTitle("CALCULADORA");                                                      //Here I set a Title
        setLayout(acomodoMarco);                                                       //Here I set the layout
        setBounds(500,300, 380, 400);                                               //I set the bounds 
        LaminasCalculadoras milamina = new LaminasCalculadoras();    
        add(milamina);                                                                        //Adding 
    }
    
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
class LaminasCalculadoras extends JPanel{
    
    
    JTextField pantalla = new JTextField("");                   //Creating the object pantalla (screen)
    JPanel milamina2 = new JPanel();                                   //Creating the panel for the buttons
    private boolean reseteo = true;
    private double resultado;
    private String ultimaOperacion;
    private String h;
    
    public LaminasCalculadoras(){
        //////////////////////////////////Screen////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(20,20));                          //Layout of the screen
        pantalla.setEnabled(false);                                          //Setting enabled the screen to avoid write in it 
        pantalla.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,50));    //Size of the screen
        add(pantalla, BorderLayout.NORTH);                          //Adding the screen
        
        
        //////////////////////////////////Buttons////////////////////////////////////////////////////////         
        milamina2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4,20,20));       //Matrix of buttons
        add(milamina2, BorderLayout.CENTER);                     //Adding the buttons in the center of the panel that has the screen in the north
        ActionListener a = new Numeros();                   //Here I put the Actionlistener in the buttons
        ActionListener b = new Operadores();
        ActionListener c = new Borrado();
        ponerBoton("7", a);
        ponerBoton("8", a);
        ponerBoton("9", a);
        ponerBoton("/", b);
        ponerBoton("4", a);
        ponerBoton("5", a);
        ponerBoton("6", a);                                                    //Here I create the buttons with the method ponerBoton
        ponerBoton("*", b);
        ponerBoton("1", a);
        ponerBoton("2", a);
        ponerBoton("3", a);
        ponerBoton("-", b);
        ponerBoton("C", c);
        ponerBoton("0", a);
        ponerBoton("=",b);
        ponerBoton("+", b);
        ultimaOperacion="=";
    }
    
    
    private void ponerBoton(String numero, ActionListener oyente){      //Method to create the Buttons and activate the action listener
        JButton boton = new JButton(numero);
        boton.addActionListener(oyente);
        milamina2.add(boton);
    }
    
    //##################### Numbers ##############################//
    private class Numeros implements ActionListener{                       //Class to write the numbers in the screen

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                         //Method
            String entrada=e.getActionCommand();                               //Getting the text of every button clicked
            if(reseteo==true){                                                              //Here I reset the screen after of click an arithemetic operator
                pantalla.setText(" ");
                reseteo=false; 
            }
                   
           pantalla.setText(pantalla.getText()+entrada);                     //Writting the text in screen
        }
        
    }
    
    //##################### Operators ##############################//
    private class Operadores implements ActionListener{                //Class to write the operators in the screen
                                                                                                   //In this class I call the method calcular to do the calculations
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                      //Method to write the operators in screen
           String operador=e.getActionCommand();
           if(reseteo==false){                                                          //Here I want to reset the screen after click an operator
               h=pantalla.getText();                                                   //Here I get what it is in screen
               pantalla.setText(" ");
               reseteo=true;
           }
           

               
          pantalla.setText(operador);                                           //Here I want to write the operator

         calcular(Double.parseDouble(h));                                    //Here I call the method to do the calculations
         ultimaOperacion = operador;                                         //This variable tells what operation to do 
           
           
           
        }
        
        public void calcular(double x){                                         //Method to do the calculations
            switch (ultimaOperacion) {
                case "+":
                    resultado+=x;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    resultado-=x;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    resultado*=x;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    resultado/=x;
                    break;
                case "=":
                    resultado=x;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            
            pantalla.setText(""+ resultado);

        }
        
    }
    
    //##################### Erase ##############################//
    private class Borrado implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pantalla.setText(" ");
            reseteo = true;
        }
        
    }
    
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

Comment: What do you mean by "operators do not appear on the screen"? The operator buttons are there without text? The operator buttons are not there, but the digit button are? Please **edit** the question and clarify. Also, please show all relevant code, including the code where the `milamina2` panel is added to the calculator window.

Comment: A better design would have a logically isolated part of the code, e.g., a separate method, doing the `pantalla.setText()` calls, rather than having them all over the place, potentially messing up what you are trying to show, as is the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `pantalla.setText(""+ resultado);` from `calcular(double x)` and move it to the following place with the following condition:

```java
calcular(Double.parseDouble(h));    //Here I call the method to do the calculations

if ("=".equals(operador)) {
    pantalla.setText(""+ resultado);
}

ultimaOperacion = operador;        //This variable tells what operation to do
```

This will only print the calculated value when "=" is being pressed.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)